# How to use graphics.h in codeblocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, bgi

I have recently started learning graphics in C++.

I tried `#include <graphics.h>` in my program in codeblocks but it shows error. Then I downloaded `graphics.h` header from a site and pasted in the *include* folder in codeblocks, yet it shows `graphics.h:No such file or directory`.

Can anyone teach me how to use `graphics.h` in codeblocks?

Comment: It was a header that was available in old Borland compilers.  Used strictly for graphics in MS-Dos apps.  You are at least 7 operating systems, 16 bits, 20 years and untold compiler versions removed from using it.

Comment: As for "Can anyone teach me how to use graphics in codeblocks?": the answer lies not in CodeBlocks (it's an IDE, *not* a compiler!), but in your target OS. If for Windows: use Windows APIs. If for DOS: check the documentation that came with the compiler you are using.

Comment: @Jongware I'm in quite the same position as Jefree. I'm a newbie in C and after a couple of basic programs I found [a code](http://www.programmingcampus.com/2013/01/circle.html) that draws a circle. Cool! And it's dead simple - literally 5 lines long. That was the power of oold graphics.h - the simplicity. Now people suggested me to learn OpenGL. :-(

Comment: @Jeyekomon You sir, just voiced my exact thoughts. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

1. First download WinBGIm from http://winbgim.codecutter.org/ Extract it.
2. Copy `graphics.h` and `winbgim.h` files in include folder of your compiler directory
3. Copy `libbgi.a` to lib folder of your compiler directory
4. In code::blocks open Settings >> Compiler and debugger >>linker settings
   click Add button  in link libraries part and browse and select `libbgi.a` file
5. In right part (i.e. other linker options) paste commands
   `-lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32`
6. Click OK

For detail information follow this [link](http://www.codeincodeblock.com/2011/09/how-to-setup-winbgim-library-in.html).

Comment: thanks,i did as u said. but when i run my program, a window appears saying that the program has stopped working. what should i do? can u help me?

Comment: I can't figure out the actual problem. Have you use getch() function? It doesn't work if you setup winbgim.

Comment: the library got an issue with the re declaration  of an int right @ line 302 ....please do the needful...

Comment: It worked with the @Aditya Ankur's answer 
```int left=0, int top=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX,```
Aditya Ankur's answer is below.

Comment: ***a window appears saying that the program has stopped working. what should i do? can u help me?*** I expect this means your compiler is too new for the 2005 binaries that are part of the download. This repository has a newer port to attempt to fix this: [https://github.com/Duthomhas/WinBGIm-fixed-sort-of-](https://github.com/Duthomhas/WinBGIm-fixed-sort-of-)

Comment: Another possibility is [SDL-BGI, a port of the BGI library that runs atop SDL](http://libxbgi.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 3):

You don't only need the header file, you need the library that goes with it. Anyway, the `include` folder is not automatically loaded, you must configure your project to do so. Right-click on it : `Build options` > `Search directories` > `Add`. Choose your `include` folder, keep the path relative.

**Edit** For further assistance, please give details about the library you're trying to load (which provides a `graphics.h` file.)

Comment: But note "the library that goes with it" needs to be compatible with the compiler you are using.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Codeblocks and Graphics.h,you can use Codeblocks-EP(I used it when I was learning C in college) then you can try

Codeblocks-EP http://codeblocks.codecutter.org/

In Codeblocks-EP , [File]->[New]->[Project]->[WinBGIm Project]

[image: Codeblocks-EP WinBGIm Project Graphics.h]

It has templates for WinBGIm projects installed and all the necessary libraries pre-installed.

OR try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20321173/5227589

Answer (score 3):

It is a tradition to use Turbo C for graphic in C/C++. But it’s also a pain in the neck. We are using Code::Blocks IDE, which will ease out our work.

Steps to run graphics code in CodeBlocks:

1. Install Code::Blocks
2. Download the required header files
3. Include graphics.h and winbgim.h
4. Include libbgi.a
5. Add Link Libraries in Linker Setting
6. include graphics.h and Save code in cpp extension

To test the setting copy paste run following code:

```
#include <graphics.h>
int main( )
{
    initwindow(400, 300, "First Sample");
    circle(100, 50, 40);
    while (!kbhit( ))
    {
        delay(200);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a complete setup instruction for Code::Blocks

[How to include graphics.h in CodeBlocks?](https://erainnovator.com/how-to-include-graphics-h-in-codeblocks/)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, in the epic DOS era there is a header file named graphics.h shipped with Borland Turbo C++ suite. If it is true, then you are out of luck because we're now in Windows era.

Answer (score 2):

- Open the file graphics.h using either of Sublime Text Editor or
  Notepad++,from the `include` folder where you have installed
  Codeblocks.
- Goto line no 302
- Delete the line and paste `int left=0, int top=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX,` in that line.
- Save the file and start Coding.