# graphics.h - installed it, why still error?

Tags: c++, bgi

So i followed instructions from an another question answer in this page about how to install graphics.h And it resulted correctly. But when i included it, it showed me this error message:

```
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\graphics.h|302|error: redefinition of 'int right'|
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\graphics.h|302|note: 'int right' previously declared here|
```

Why did this happend? Can you please help me fix this problem?

This is where i got the information from:
[How to use graphics.h in codeblocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313534/how-to-use-graphics-h-in-codeblocks?rq=1)

Comment: Could you please share the code where you have declared variable "right"?

Comment: the error is stated inside the library

Comment: my code just prints "graphics" on the screen. I just tested it out.

Comment: Looks like it points at the same line. Did you include it twice? Does it have a header guard?

Comment: I dont know. My code it 9 lines long total. It seems the problem is inside the library

Comment: Where did you find this file, and where is the question and answer you mention? You normally can't just drop a header in your include directory and hope that it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you followed the last resolution provided in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313534/how-to-use-graphics-h-in-codeblocks?rq=1) you have specified?

1. Open the file graphics.h using either of Sublime Text Editor or Notepad++,from the include folder where you have installed Codeblocks.
2. Goto line no 302
3. Delete the line and paste int left=0, int top=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX, in that line.
4. Save the file and start Coding.

Comment: Thank you! Rewritting the line fixed the problem. Thank you once again!