# Library <graphics.h> is missing for MinGW-W64

Tags: c, windows, mingw-w64, bgi

Compiler: **MinGW-W64 GCC-8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh)**

Missing library: **graphics.h**

---

It seems like this library was not installed by default. If such case is true, where can I get it?

As a side note, I am not interested in installing a full IDE like Visual Studio just to use this one library.

Comment: What is it? It's not a standard C or POSIX header file.

Comment: AFAIK, `graphics.h` is _not_ part of the standard `mingw` install. But, I've never used it myself, so I could [easily] be wrong. My guess is that `graphics.h` comes from some other library that you have to install [and you should _not_ need an IDE]. From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41740791/graphics-h-not-working-in-code-blocks-with-mingw-in-windows-7-64bit it appears that `graphics.h` is part of [an ancient] Borland graphics library, so _not_ intrinsically part of `mingw` Maybe _too_ ancient/unsupported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into this for 5 minutes, I think you will need to install either [sdl-bgi](https://github.com/genpfault/sdl-bgi/blob/master/README.md) or [WinBGIm](https://winbgim.codecutter.org/).  Since MSYS2 doesn't seem to have packages for these, you would need to compile those projects from source.  This means you would need to figure out the correct set of configuration optiosn and possibly fix any build errors.  If you do succeed in doing that, you might consider contributing your work as an MSYS2 package so others can benefit from it ( https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages ).