# How to use Mingw graphic library in DEV-C++?

Tags: c++, c, graphics, mingw

I am using MinGW64 for compile my codes.
How to use the graphics library in Dev-C++(MinGW64) in Windows?
Or write a simple example?

Comment: what graphics library? you mean BGI/WinBGI? What windows? what is the exact problem you having?

Comment: 1-graphics.h
2-i do not know.
3-windows10
4-i cant use rectangle function for draw a rectangle.

Comment: `graphics.h` header is very common filename in any gfx api the real name of lib you using is important if your code has something like `int gdriver = DETECT, gmode;
    initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode, "");` then its BGI however ancient BGI was designed for MS-DOS in order to run such code in win10 you need a win10 compatible port of BGI  for example WinBGI is old windows port (not sure if it runs on win10 I never used it) in order to use it you have to download such lib and properly link it to your executable see probable [duplicate of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72673653/2521214)

Comment: also beware any BGI port you  found will be most likely 32bit so you have to compile your program as win32 executable too ...

Answer (score 0):

Dev-C++ hasn't released any new versions in the last 7 years. I think this software was abandoned. I used Dev-C++ a long time ago to, but I switched to [Code::Blocks](https://www.codeblocks.org/) and I remember the transition was very smooth.

I made a short explanation on how to configure MinGW-w64 in [Code::Blocks](https://www.codeblocks.org/) at https://winlibs.com/#usage-codeblocks and I assume it should be quite similar in Dev-C++.

As for `graphics.h`: this is not part of MinGW-w64, but the following projects provide it:

- SDL_bgi: https://sdl-bgi.sourceforge.io/
- winbgim: http://winbgim.codecutter.org/

Both these packages can be built with MinGW-w64.