# Installation for using graphics.h

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, graphics, mingw-w64, windows-11

can anyone tell me how to install bgi for c language in vscode and how to setup the graphics library to use graphics.h? I want to know how to install graphics library for my computer graphics class in college?

i tried watching youtube video but didn't got good reply

Comment: you need [WinBGI](https://winbgim.codecutter.org) or other emulator for BGI running on Windows however I doubt there is one for 64bit platform so your projects must target 32bit executables in order to use those ancient 32bit emulators of even more ancient BGI... I see that in that link (first google hit) is also source code for the lib so you might even do a 64bit port of it to use in 64bit executables if you know how ...

Answer (score 0):

There are actually multiple libraries out there that provide BGI for C:

- https://winbgim.codecutter.org/
- https://sdl-bgi.sourceforge.io/ (uses SDL as underlying library, which makes it cross-platform)

Comment: can you explain anything about how to use thsi with my mysys2 compiler or i need to install mingw according to winbgi

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72673611/library-graphics-h-is-missing-for-mingw-w64