# What can I do if code::blocks shows error when I try to use graphics.h for c/c++?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, bgi

Today I tried to write a code using graphics.h in code::blocks. But instead of showing appropriate result, it showed "no such file or directory". But, isn't graphics.h is one of the header file of c/c++? So, if there is any solution, tell me what to do so that I can use it in code::blocks. Or, if you have any other better substitutive idea, it is sure to be appreciated.

Comment: "it showed error". Wouldn't it make sense to tell people exactly what error you are getting? Please read how to post a [mcve].

Comment: Use a decent graphics library instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use graphics.h in codeblocks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313534/how-to-use-graphics-h-in-codeblocks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graphics.h is not a part of Standard C++. It is the main header for the Borland Graphics Library that originated with Borland C about 30 years ago. It has been obsolete for about 20 years.

C++ doesn't officially recognize the existence of pixels, so you need an external library to do graphics. It's against the rules to for me to do this, so don't tell anyone, but [take a look at SDL.](https://www.libsdl.org/)