# How can I use graphics header file in codeBlock?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, bgi

Recently I start a c++ project .For this project I need to use graphics but in CodeBlock I Can't use graphics header file .

here [How to use graphics.h in codeblocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313534/how-to-use-graphics-h-in-codeblocks) I found a solution but it's does not work. When i simply run this code

```
#include<graphics.h>
int main(){  

    return 0;
}
```

It is run with no error.But When I run this code then my program in crushed.

```
#include<graphics.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int gd=DETECT,gm,left=100,top=100,right=200,bottom=200,x=300,y=150,radius=50;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\TC\\BGI");
    rectangle(left, top, right, bottom);
    circle(x, y, radius);
    bar(left + 300, top, right + 300, bottom);
    line(left - 10, top + 150, left + 410, top + 150);
    ellipse(x, y + 200, 0, 360, 100, 50);
    outtextxy(left + 100, top + 325, "My First C Graphics Program");

    getch();
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

Give me a solution .

Comment: codeblocks not working with graphics.h so good...  try visual studio.

Comment: thanks for your Suggestion . Actually i am very noob in programming . I only use codeblock and i have no idea on other IDE . Ok I will try Visual Studio .

Comment: "_my program in crushed_" is not a helpful fault report. Please include the error message you are seeing as part of your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if code::blocks shows error when I try to use graphics.h for c/c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43958082/what-can-i-do-if-codeblocks-shows-error-when-i-try-to-use-graphics-h-for-c-c)